# Feeds reader for Android

Tags: java, android, rss-reader

I need to build an android's feeds reader, but I have no idea where to start. I know the basis of java's programming, and I would appreciate a lot some guide lines. can any one help me ? Thanks

Comment: So you know Java. But you are beginning with Android?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-rss/ You can download and check the source code.. but before that learn an object oriented language.

Comment: Yes. Only basics, but I have some notions about it...

Comment: @NelsonSilva: _Some_ notions? Anyway, refer to _Yul's_ answer. I would however recommend that before you take the plunge, you should start with the basics. Start looking at the samples from the SDK.

Comment: those are tutorials, I want to do it by my way, not following someone's way. I only needed guide lines, but I see that you cant help me here...

Answer (score 4):

I simple google and got these:

1. [Android RSS Feed Reader Example](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.com/2012/06/android-rss-feed-reader-example.html)
2. [Android RSS Reader Tutorial](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/08/android-rss-reader-tutorial.html)
3. [android-feed-reader](http://code.google.com/p/android-feed-reader/)
4. [Android Development Tutorial – A Simple Twitter Feed Reader](http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/android-programming-tutorial-a-simple-twitter-feed-reader/)
5. [Build a mobile RSS reader](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-androidrss/)
6. [Android sample application: Simple RSS reader](http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/android-sample-application-simple-rss-reader) based on 5

Comment: Awww. You shouldn't have. He had googled it. ;-) +1 anyway.

Comment: those are tutorials, I want to do it by my way, not following someone's way. I only needed guide lines, but I see that you cant help me here...

Comment: I can't understand what so called `your way` when you know nothing. If you know nothing, learn the basics from others then change by yourself. Even a detail tutorial can't help you so what can help you? `Reading XML using SAX` is the basic. I just wonder did you read all the artical. The fifth from IBM is very detail. It explain from data structure to parsing xml.